# In UV Editor, is there a way to set rotation of selected mesh to 0 (reset/align to view)

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

When I do an unwrap on a cube with seams it goes diagonally in the UV editor view. I use ctrl+p to pack and it almost aligns it to the view/texture but is there a way to unwrap it so it is aligned to 0 or 90°? Or is there a way to reset the rotation after (there is no rotation value in the 'n' panel)? When I do Rkey+90 it is relative, not absolute. See what I mean?

Comment: In some cases [UV Squares](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/UV/Uv_Squares) addon operator Snap Vertices To Axis will do that, but note that it will not preserve curved islands (if any). If they should be left as not squares (e.g. to avoid distortion) then you need to go with straightening via pinning.

Answer (score 2):

You can use UV Squares addon for that.

1. Enable it in User Preferences by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> > *Addons* > *UV Squares*.
   If you don't have the addon, save [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Radivarig/UvSquares/master/uv_squares.py) to your blender-folder/scripts/addons and refresh the list.
2. Then you can find it in the Image/UV Editor in the left panel <kbd>T</kbd> > *Misc* tab.
3. Just select the rotated cube unwrap and press *To Grid by Shape*:

   [image]

**Note:** This works only if your UVs are quads.

Answer (score 2):

There is an add-on that align the UV island based on a selected edge, it may help you. [Align UV Island Add-on](https://gumroad.com/l/PTSa). See an [example video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WemezIaOjXo).

Answer (score 1):

Nope unfortunately. But if you have to have all the UV line up nicely. I can suggest this.

1. Select the midline of the UV island.
2. Hit <kbd>P</kbd> to pin the whole mid line.
3. Turn on live unwrap in the UV editor menu > uvs > live unwrap.
4. With the pinned vertices selected, scale along either X or Y to zero to straighten the selection.
5. Rotate the island matching the grid line as closely as possible

There you have it, just a work around.